# Getting error while downloading the file using Blob created from URI Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

```
client = storage.Client()
blob = Blob.from_string("gs://current-project/images/myimage.jpeg")
print(blob.bucket.name)
fileName = blob.name.split('/')[-1]
print(fileName)
print(blob)
blob.download_to_filename('test1.jpeg')
```

I am able to print the bucket name, blob info and fileName as well. But when I try to download the image it gives me an error.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_connection'
```

I am not sure what I am missing. If I use this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-python) to download the image and explicitly specify the bucket name and create blob object from bucket it works fine. I am not understanding the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having this error because you are using the `blob` created with a local constructor `blob = Blob.from_string`. With [this method](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.from_string), you don't retrieve the blob object from your bucket, you just create an empty object with this name in your local environment.

As you have stated the code sample from the [documentation you linked](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#code-samples) works fine since it gets the blob from the [bucket](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html#google.cloud.storage.client.Client.get_bucket) with an internal API when calling the methods.

```
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
```

Comment: Ohh thank you. I was able to solve it by just passing the client as an argument in `Blob.from_string`.